# Is there a way to modify external list form with Infopath?

Tags: infopath, bcs

I would like to modify an external list form with infopath like I do with custom lists.
However, even if I select "create infopath form" when creating my external list, it doesn't seems I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, and here is an article on MSDN about how to do this. Please, check, if you're doing things right:

- [How to: Customize External List Forms Using Microsoft InfoPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886.aspx)

Comment: omlin: to highten the quality of our answers here on SPSE it would be nice with a short description of a possible solution, and **then** a link :-) Links unfortunately come and go, but we plan to stay a while...

Comment: Actually, I don't know what is the reason of such behavour, because @Nico haven't provided detailed information on how is the list created and what is the error message. So, I can't determine what is he doing wrong. And the MSDN "How to" document is too large, to copy-past it here. So I decided to provide the link.
But anyway, I will keep in mind your advice, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the same actions as standard list, like "edit in infopath", or the form settings in list settings. I did not try designer :)